# TikZ Scale array of matrices

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code produces a 3x3 matrix (upper left corner) and an 2x2 array of 3x3 matrices:

[image]

How can I reduce the size of the matrix array such that it has the same size as the matrix `M`? I tried `scale=0.5` which had no effect. I want to reduce the size only of the matrix array and not of the entire TikZ picture.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\tikzset{
  matrixstyle/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    nodes={
      draw
    }
}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \matrix (M) [matrixstyle]{
            .1 & .1 & .0  \\
            .0 & .2 & .8 \\
            .2 & .0 & .8 \\
        };

        \begin{scope} [shift={(M.south)}, below = 0cm of M.south]
            \matrix (M11) [matrixstyle]{
                .1 & .1 & .0  \\
                .0 & .5 & .0 \\
                .3 & .0 & .0 \\
            };
            \matrix (M12) [matrixstyle, right = 0cm of M11]{
                .3 & .2 & .0  \\
                .0 & .3 & .9 \\
                .2 & .1 & .0 \\
            };
            \matrix (M21) [matrixstyle, below = 0cm of M11]{
                .0 & .0 & .0  \\
                .0 & .0 & .2 \\
                .0 & .0 & .2 \\
            };
            \matrix (M22) [matrixstyle, right = 0cm of M21]{
                .9 & .3 & .0  \\
                .0 & .3 & .9 \\
                .5 & .0 & .8 \\
            };
        \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `scale = <scale>` and `every node/.style = {scale = <scale>}` ... whether this is a good idea is a whole different question

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\tikzset{
  matrixstyle/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    nodes={
      draw
    }
}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \matrix (M) [matrixstyle]{
            .1 & .1 & .0  \\
            .0 & .2 & .8 \\
            .2 & .0 & .8 \\
        };

        \begin{scope} [shift={([xshift = -11pt]M.south)}, below = 0cm of M.south, scale = 0.47, every node/.style = {scale = 0.47}]
            \matrix (M11) [matrixstyle]{
                .1 & .1 & .0  \\
                .0 & .5 & .0 \\
                .3 & .0 & .0 \\
            };
            \matrix (M12) [matrixstyle, right = -6pt of M11]{
                .3 & .2 & .0  \\
                .0 & .3 & .9 \\
                .2 & .1 & .0 \\
            };
            \matrix (M21) [matrixstyle, below = -6pt of M11]{
                .0 & .0 & .0  \\
                .0 & .0 & .2 \\
                .0 & .0 & .2 \\
            };
            \matrix (M22) [matrixstyle, right = -6pt of M21]{
                .9 & .3 & .0  \\
                .0 & .3 & .9 \\
                .5 & .0 & .8 \\
            };
        \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do I need `[xshift = -11pt]`? Is there an exact solution, which does the centering automatically?